# how to trigger jquery function when field automatically filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an order form with multiple lines and columns
`Product_id  Qty  price`

Quantity and price are automatically filled out when `Product` is chosen in a drop down list.

At the end of the form, I have a field that sore the total amount `<span id="total"></span>`

I made the code below to calculate the total amount of the order but it doesn't work when `qty` and `price` are automatically filled. It does work if I type in `qty` or `price`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".qty, .price").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".qty").each(function() {
            var self = $(this),
                price = self.next(".price"),
                subtotal = parseInt(self.val(), 10) * parseFloat(price.val(), 10);
            total += (subtotal || 0);
        });
        $("#total").text(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.trigger('change')` or `.change()` while changing the textbox value from code:

```
 $(".qty, .price").trigger('change');
```

or

```
 $(".qty, .price").change();
```

**For Example:**

```
 $(".qty").val('30').change();
```

Comment: I did this but still doesn't work: <code>jQuery(function($) {

$(".qty, .price").trigger('change', function() {
var total = 0;
$(".qty").each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
        price = self.next(".price"),
        subtotal = parseInt(self.val(), 10) * parseFloat(price.val(), 10);
    total += (subtotal || 0);
});
$("#total").text(total);
});

});</code>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its correct but, have you tried using documnt.load()? you could put the code in a function that you call when page its loaded and when field value has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to separate you code into a new function such as:

```
var calculate = function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".qty").each(function() {
        var self = $(this),
            price = self.next(".price"),
            subtotal = parseInt(self.val(), 10) * parseFloat(price.val(), 10);
        total += (subtotal || 0);
    });
    $("#total").text(total);
};
$(".qty, .price").change(calculate);
```

Then call it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling a Function on page load and do it like this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  YourFunction();


YourFunction() function{

     // insert your code
 }
});
```

Then you can say

```
$(".qty, .price").change(function() {
     YourFunction();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this function and I call it when the product ID is selected but there is a delay on updating the qty and the price. function runs only when the next product is selected. I there a way to delay the function? `function caltotal() {
        var total = 0;       
        $(".qty").each(function() {
            var self = $(this),
                price = self.next(".price"),
                subtotal = parseInt(self.val(), 10) * parseFloat(price.val(), 10);
            total += (subtotal || 0);
        });
        $("#total").text(total);
    
}`